# ElasticSearch authentication error with ElasticCloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have just set up a new ElasticSearch cluster on ElasticCloud and I am trying to follow the [help documentation](https://cloud.elastic.co/#/help/).

It says you can post a document as follows:

```
curl https://<id>.<region>.aws.found.io:9243/my_index/my_type -XPOST -d '{"title": "One", "tags": ["ruby"] }'
```

So I am trying this with my own URL, but I am getting:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"action [indices:data/write/index] requires authentication","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"action [indices:data/write/index] requires authentication","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}},"status":401}
```

Is there something else I need to do first? The help documentation doesn't mention any extra steps.

Comment: Figured it out - need to supply basic-auth username and password in the URL, like `https://username:password@<id>.<region>...`. The documentation doesn't make this clear.

Answer (score 3):

The authentication can be done in basic-auth format:

```
https://username:password@<id>.<region>.found.io:9243
```

Users and roles can be managed via Kibana in In Elasticsearch version 5.0 and later.

Comment: This did not work for me. Received error: org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: java.io.IOException: <my username>:<my password>@d972<hidden characters>dd7d665aee2.us-east-1.aws.found.io: invalid IPv6 address This is with the Hight Level REST client for Java

Comment: **curl -XGET https://<user>:<pass>@<id>.<region>.aws.<...>:<port>/_nodes/stats**

output-

**{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}**

I checked another way also-

 **curl -XGET --user <uname>:<pass> "https://<id>.<region>.gcp.<....>:<port>/_cluster/health?pretty" **

**{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}**

I am getting error 404 for both the curl requests